# Mongoose does not connect to mongodb at the first attempt but succeeds at second

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I enabled authentication in MongoDB. I created a user in the "admin" db with username "test" and password "password". The user has the role "dbAdmin" for database "testdb".

I am connecting using mongoose. Here is the mongo URI 
mongodb://test@127.0.0.1:27017/testdb?authSource=admin.

The first connection is rejected by mongo and it connects on the second attempt. Can anyone help me understand why it does not connect in one try? My database and the node service are on localhost.

Here are the logs

```
[2020-04-28T06:01:37.489] [DEBUG] => Trying to connect to mongodb://test@127.0.0.1:27017/testdb?authSource=admin
(node:74504) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
[2020-04-28T06:01:38.063] [INFO] => Server running at: http://0.0.0.0:6001
[2020-04-28T06:01:38.077] [INFO] => Successfully connected to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379
[2020-04-28T06:01:38.103] [FATAL] => { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:433:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pool.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at createConnection (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:577:14)
    at connect (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1007:11)
    at callback (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:93:5)
    at provider.auth.err (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:367:21)
    at _authenticateSingleConnection (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/auth_provider.js:66:11)
    at sendAuthCommand (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:193:16)
    at _callback (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:320:5)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at processMessage (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/applicationdeveloper/Sarthak/Projects/Test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
[2020-04-28T06:01:38.106] [FATAL] => An unhandled exception has occurred
[2020-04-28T06:01:38.395] [INFO] => Successfully connected to MongoDB at 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Comment: What do the mongod logs say about these connections?

Comment: And, is this on the current version of mongodb driver?